# MOC3041/42/43 differences

Tags: mains, opto-isolator, triac

I have a question regarding the MOC30XX series opto-couplers. What is the real difference in their operation? So far I know only that the forward current of the input driving diode is 15, 10 and 5 mA respectively. 
Is there any difference in their theory of operation, ie. auto turn-off at 0 cross etc? I would appreciate all info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all have triac outputs. Triacs have the intrinsic feature to turn **off** at currents below the holding current. The control circuit takes care not to turn on immediately when the voltage isn't near zero. That makes it safe to use that part as a on/off switch in a simplyfied circuit for inductive and capacitive load. You cannot control phase-angle that way, though.

The MOC3041/42/43 are binned for manufacturing tolerances of the optocouple. That's it.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Let me ask a followup question. If I supply the current for the input LED constantly (no switching, LED is ON all the time), should the connected triac fire itself after zero cross automatically (Assuming resistive load)? I am asking this, because I wonder either zero cross detector is necessary here for the MCU just to turn the load ON/OFF.

Comment: Do you mean "Yes it will turn on" or "yes you need zero cross detector"? Sorry, just want to make sure.

Comment: It turns on automatically after first zero-cross then. The zero-cross dectector is an add-on which helps you simplyfying your output circuit for inductive loads.